# Using Jquery Mobile dynamically generated dialog box opens multiple times

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, event-handling

In a multi page template,I have three category pages `(comedy, action, drama)` that you can swipe between each containing rows of images `(Seinfeld, Modern Family, Family Guy, Big Bang)`. Clicking on an individual image should open a dialog box `(Seinfeld summary)`, close when you click the close button, and stay close. Initially it works, then what happens is based on the number images click after two, it opens and closes n -1 (clicking the 3rd image, opens the dialog box twice).

what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you show as a part of your code? I think I know what is your problem but I want to be sure. Worst case scenario show as only part of your code where you bind a click event to the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your code I can be sure but I think I understand what is happening to you.

You have a problem with multiple event binding. Because of **`jQuery Mobile`** architecture it is possible to bind an event numerous time to some object.

I have an blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)** on **`jQuery Mobile`** page events handling and there's a chapter dedicated to this problem, just search for the chapter **Prevent multiple event triggering**. Or it can be found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

In few words always unbind event before you bind it to some object to prevent this from happening:

```
$('#test-button').die('click').live('click', function(e) {
    alert('Button click');
});
```